# Control order of WAR file deployment in JBoss EAP 7.2.0

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, jboss-eap-7

I have developed two Spring Boot applications, one is Cloud Config Server and the other is a Spring Boot application that fetches property from Config Server. I have deployed the two applications as WAR files in JBoss EAP. I am deploying the WAR files in sequence, deploying the Config Server before the other application. Problem is happening after I restart the server, the second war file is getting deployed before the war file for Config Server.

I Jboss EAP 7.2.0, how will I ensure that the WAR file for Config Server is always deployed before the WAR file of the other application?

Answer (score 0):

You can control the startup order of deployment by using jboss-all.xml deployment descriptor to declare dependencies between the deployments.

**Example:** 
If you want `foo.ear` is deployed before `bar.ear` then you can create an `bar.ear/META-INF/jboss-all.xml` file like this:

```
<jboss xmlns="urn:jboss:1.0">
   <jboss-deployment-dependencies xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-dependencies:1.0">
     <dependency name="foo.ear" />
   </jboss-deployment-dependencies>
</jboss>
```

[1] https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.1/html/configuration_guide/deploying_applications#control_order_deployments

[2] https://access.redhat.com/solutions/88763